# Make text wrap under text only when image is present

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to align text to the right or left of an image. This is easily achieved with float or flex. However, I'm attempting to do this with vertical align.

What I'm seeing is, I can give the impression that the text is floating left or right by using the vertical align.

The problem I have is, when the amount of text exceeds the width of the container, the text breaks (as expected) to a new line. But instead of being a new line straight underneath the original, and still to the right/left of the picture, the break inserts the text under the image.

Some very trivial code demonstrates this

```
<img src="https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png" style="vertical-align:top"/> Please  enter lots of words
```

https://jsfiddle.net/metkc72p/

I don't want to use float or flex as the purpose of this is to understand the limitations.

My question is purely if I can do anything about this awkward splitting.

The image demonstrates this well. The first is what I'm trying to achieve, the second is what I'm currently getting!
[image]

Comment: WHY can't you use float or flex? I mean, if someone was to suggest using a css table or css columns, would that be out of the question too?

Comment: Simply because I want to learn about the limitations of vertical align. It may be the wrong tool for the job, which I'm fine with, but that is also an acceptable answer :) However, I'm interested to know why this behaviour exists (if possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image and your text are both inline-level elements.

From the browser's perspective, the image and the text are all on the same line.

From your perspective, imagine the image to be just another word on the line, but with `font-size: 3em`.

Because of the taller height of the image, the text is forced to wrap far below, resulting in a tall gap within the paragraph.

But if the text and image are equal size, then the wrapping looks more natural.

```css
img {
  height: 15px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png"> Here is some content... I'm hoping there is enough content so that it runs over multiple 'lines' (rows) so you can see where the text breaks, it ends up underneath
the image. I'd expect there to be 3 or 4 rows of text until it breaks like this, and not break at the first
```

[revised demo](https://jsfiddle.net/metkc72p/7/)

If you don't want the text to wrap under the image, use another method, such as flexbox:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png"> Here is some content... I'm hoping there is enough content so that it runs over multiple 'lines' (rows) so you can see where the text breaks, it ends up underneath
the image. I'd expect there to be 3 or 4 rows of text until it breaks like this, and not break at the first
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>
<img src="https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png" style="vertical-align:top"/>
</div>
<div>
Here is some content... I'm hoping there is enough content so that it runs over multiple 'lines' (rows) so you can see where the text breaks, it ends up underneath the image. I'd expect there to be 3 or 4 rows of text until it breaks like this, and not break at the first 
</div>
```

Use div and give `width` and `float` to the div. Check this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/metkc72p/6/

Answer (score -1):

You should use `float: left` property.
You can see it here: https://jsfiddle.net/metkc72p/5/